# Find rules matching a transaction in arulessequence R package

Tags: r, arules

How can we find rules (mined through cSPADE function) matching a temporal sequence of transactions.

For example, using Zaki data from the arulessequence package:

```
> as(zaki,"data.frame")
       items sequenceID eventID SIZE
1      {C,D}          1      10    2
2    {A,B,C}          1      15    3
3    {A,B,F}          1      20    3
4  {A,C,D,F}          1      25    4
5    {A,B,F}          2      15    3
6        {E}          2      20    1
7    {A,B,F}          3      10    3
8    {D,G,H}          4      10    3
9      {B,F}          4      20    2
10   {A,G,H}          4      25    3
```

rules are mined through:

```
> s4 <- cspade(t, parameter = list(support = 0.4))
> r2 <- ruleInduction(s4, confidence = 0.5, control = list(verbose = TRUE))
> as(r2,"data.frame")
                   rule support confidence lift
1        <{D}> => <{F}>     0.5        1.0  1.0
2      <{D}> => <{B,F}>     0.5        1.0  1.0
3        <{D}> => <{B}>     0.5        1.0  1.0
4        <{B}> => <{A}>     0.5        0.5  0.5
5        <{D}> => <{A}>     0.5        1.0  1.0
6        <{F}> => <{A}>     0.5        0.5  0.5
7    <{D},{F}> => <{A}>     0.5        1.0  1.0
8      <{B,F}> => <{A}>     0.5        0.5  0.5
9  <{D},{B,F}> => <{A}>     0.5        1.0  1.0
10   <{D},{B}> => <{A}>     0.5        1.0  1.0
```

Lets say a new sequence of transactions is provided as follows.

```
       items sequenceID eventID SIZE
1      {A,C}          5      10    1
2    {B,F,E}          5      15    3
3      {B,G}          5      20    2
4    {A,C,H}          5      25    3
```

The objective is to find rules fulfilling the lhs of r2. The target outcome (drafted by hand) is:

```
                   rule support confidence lift
4        <{B}> => <{A}>     0.5        0.5  0.5
6        <{F}> => <{A}>     0.5        0.5  0.5
8      <{B,F}> => <{A}>     0.5        0.5  0.5
```

I hope I have explained the problem properly, thnx!

Comment: Could you please include the code and data directly within your question to reproduce this?

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity.